# Read a specific thing in a line of a textbox and put in in a windowsform

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader

I have that text file with a few lines of text. In each line there are three necessary pieces of information: Username, Date and Time.

I added the lines to a `ListBox` control via a `StreamReader`, and above that control there is a `TextBox` control. I want to put the username in the `TextBox`, but I have no idea how.

Here is the code:

```
namespace Zeiterfassung
{
    public partial class Uebersicht : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sPath = @"C:\VSTO\Projects\Zeiterfassung\Zeiterfassung\obj\Debug\Kommt.txt";

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sPath))
            {
                while(!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    lb_Kommt.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the lines in the txt-file are all similar to this:

```
User: KIV\vischer, Datum: 10.09.2018, Zeit: 10:49
```

I need to put "KIV\Vischer" in the `TestBox`, not in the `ListBox`.

Comment: You could use a regex or just a string.split

Comment: You have multiple lines but a single TextBox

Comment: from which line in the file would you like to take the value?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want every single line of the txt file as an item in a listbox. I did this already. But now I need to filter out specific things within the lines I need in my TEXTbox

Comment: @ADyson the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a RegEx.

It could look like this:

```
User: (?<user>[^,]*?), Datum: (?<datum>[\d]{1,2}\.[\d]{1,2}\.[\d]{2,4}), Zeit: (?<zeit>[\d]{1,2}:[\d]{2})
```

You can find more details (and a live demo) here:

https://regex101.com/r/1YaMxz/2

Access the values:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    username = match.Groups["user"].Value;
}
```